# How to get the link from these images and put all in PictureBoxes?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm searching 9 hours to get the link of these images and put all in `PictureBoxes`, I've tried several times to get the "get element by id, tag name..." I'm very confused, this hierarchy of tags is very difficult because there are several other tags with the same names.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="FirstClass" id="pageID">
    <li class="coverPage">...</li>

    <li class="coverPage">
    <a href="https://myfirstsite.com/post" title="My Site Page">
    <img src="https://myfirst.com/post/image.jpg" title="Image of This Post">
    <li class="coverPage">...</li>

    <li class="coverPage">

        <a href="https://myfirstsite.com/post" title="My Site Page">
        <img src="https://myfirst.com/post/image.jpg" title="Image of This Post">

        </li>
```

**The idea**
[image]

**Try**

```
If WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
    If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString = ("https://myfirst.com/") Then
        Dim ImgTags As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("img")

        For Each element As HtmlElement In ImgTags
            Dim ImgUri As String = element.GetAttribute("src")
            PictureBox1.ImageLocation = ImgUri
        Next
    End If
End If
```

**Try 2** ( ??? :s)

```
Dim PicsTag As New ArrayList
Dim countPics As Integer = 0

For Each item As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("img")
    PicsTag.Add(item.InnerText)
    Me.Controls("Label" & countPics.tostring).Text = PicsTag(0)
    countPics = +1
    ListBox1 ???
Next
```

*Note**: There exists any tool that can extract and convert these tags to VB.NET?

Comment: Don't worry about the Html tags nesting. Subscribed to the `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event. In the event handler, insert a check: `If WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then (...) End If`. When the document is completed, the code in the `If/End If` block will execute. There, you get the collection of all the IMG tags: `Dim ImgTags As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("img")`. Iterate the collection: `For Each element As HtmlElement In ImgTags` get the links `Dim ImgUri as string = element.GetAttribute("src")`

Comment: Then you can download the Image (`WebClient` comes in handy here). Or set a `PicureBox.ImageLocation = ImgUri`.

Comment: Jimi, thanks for replying! I forgot to mention one detail, I will correct my question.

Comment: You're setting the `ImageLocation` property of the same `PictureBox` over and over. If you're planning to get all the Images (unknown number), you'll need a `List(Of PictureBox)`. Extract all the links to a `List(Of String)`, create a new `PictureBox` for each Image link, set its properties (`ImageLocation`, `Size` and `SizeMode`, mostly) then add it to the `List(Of PictureBox)`. Insert all the `PictureBoxes` in the `List` in a `TableLayoutPanel` (used as a presentation helper) and you're done.

Comment: I've never worked with picturebox list jimi :/

Comment: At class scope: `Private WebImages As List(Of PictureBox) = new List(Of PictureBox)`. Create a new `PictureBox`:  `Dim pctWebImage As New PictureBox With { .Size = New Size(150, 150), .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom, .ImageLocation = ImgUri }`. Add the new `PictureBox` to the List:  `WebImages.Add(pctWebImage)` . When the loop is complete: `FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.AddRange(WebImages.ToArray())`. Try first with a `FlowLayoutPanel`, its automatic layout feature can help get you started. Try it out. If it doesn't get out right, I'll post an example.

Comment: I'ts right? http://prntscr.com/l7r7qh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182124/discussion-between-sergio-wilker-and-jimi).

Comment: Hey jimi, see the chat!

Answer (score 0):

The *extraction* of non-generic informations (specific elements and related details) from a web page, requires an analysis of the `HTML` structure.
The main objective is to identify a common logic that describes the distribution of the containers of these elements. This isn't, usually, a difficult task, because the source of these elements (links, text, images) is (most likely) a DataBase of some sort. The elements are sequentially *assembled/wrapped* in `HTML` tags for presentation, using a repeated pattern.

The Web Page you are referring to has the following structure:

```
<Body> --
       -- Non-interesting elements
       -- <DIV class="[className]"> containers of the elements we are looking for
          -- <A title="" href=""> Anchor linking to a details page. Contains a Title text and the
                                  details page URI. "title" and "href" are attributes of the <A> tag
              -- <IMG src="">  URI of the Image. It could be a complex structure.
                               In this case, a simple, direct link

              -- <>  Non-interesting sub-elements of <A>
          -- <> Non-interesting sub-elements of <DIV>
```

We are interested in all the `<DIV>` elements of class `[className]`, because these are the containers (parent) of the elements we're after.
Thus, the first step is to extract all these `<DIV>` elements.
This is easily accomplished using the [GetElementsByTagName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname?view=netframework-4.7.2) method. This method is available for each `HTML` element, because each `HTML` element can be parant of other, nested elements.

```
.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("DIV").OfType(Of HtmlElement).
          Where(Function(t) t.GetAttribute("[className]") = "[The className we're after]")
```

This Linq query will return all  elements having the required `[className]`.
To extract the informations contained in the children `<A>` and `<IMG>` tags, we just repeat the same procedure on each  element found:

```
For Each [<DIV> element] As HtmlElement In [<DIV> elements collection]
    Dim Anchor As HtmlElement = [<DIV> element].GetElementsByTagName("A").OfType(Of HtmlElement).First()
    Dim IMG As HtmlElement = [<DIV> element].GetElementsByTagName("IMG").OfType(Of HtmlElement).First()
Next
```

We then extract the Element's attributes, using the [GetAttribute()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement.GetAttribute);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) method.
All Attributes are, of course, string values.

```
 Dim AttributeValue as String = [Element].GetAttribute("[AttributeName]")
```

What a `WebBrowser` class or `WinForms/WPF` Control is used to acquire an `HTML` page, it's necessary to subscribe to it's [DocumentCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) event.
This event is raised each time a `WebBrowser` has completed the composition of a known part of the Document.
When the Page contains `IFrames` or `Scripts` that update the Page in distinct moments, the `DocumentCompleted` event is raised multiple times.

The Document is loaded completely when the [WebBrowser.ReadyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.readystate?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.ReadyState);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) is `WebBrowserReadyState.Complete`.

An example:

```
 Dim wBrowser As WebBrowser = New WebBrowser()
 wBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
 AddHandler wBrowser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf wBrowser_DocumentCompleted
 WebLinkBrowser.Navigate("[Web URI]")

 Dim DIVClassName As String = "[Some className]"

 '(...)

 Private Sub wBrowser_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim Browser As WebBrowser = CType(sender, WebBrowser)
    If Browser.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then

        Dim DivTags As List(Of HtmlElement) =
            Browser.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("DIV").
                OfType(Of HtmlElement).
                Where(Function(t) t.GetAttribute("className") = DIVClassName).ToList()

        For Each element As HtmlElement In DivTags
            Dim elmAnchor As HtmlElement = element.GetElementsByTagName("A").OfType(Of HtmlElement).First()
            Dim AnchorTitle As String = elmAnchor.GetAttribute("title")
            Dim AnchorURI As String = elmAnchor.GetAttribute("href")

            Dim elmImage As HtmlElement = element.GetElementsByTagName("IMG").OfType(Of HtmlElement).First()
            Dim ImgSource as String = elmImage.GetAttribute("src")
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

[Sample project of a Web Scraper](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y9KU9YLBg7TJbWiqDvmlvvcwkB_NSmFq) (Google Drive).